# Performance issues with converting mp3 file input stream to byte output stream

Tags: java, audio

I would like to extract byte array from a given mp3 file in order to apply fast fourier transform on the latter. The performed FFT will give me some features for my pet-project musical -- recommendation system.

I have written the following code to extract the bytes from a given mp3 file:

```
public class TrackSample {

private static byte[] readBytesInPredefinedFormat(TargetDataLine format, InputStream inStream) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        int count = format.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        if (count > 0) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    inStream.close();
    return bytes;
}

public static byte[] getTrackBytes(String pathToTrackSample) throws IOException, LineUnavailableException {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pathToTrackSample);
    final AudioFormat format = CurrentAudioFormat.getAudioFormat(); //Fill AudioFormat with the wanted settings
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

    TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    line.open(format);
    line.start();

    return readBytesInPredefinedFormat(line, fileInputStream);
    }
}
```

And the specified audio format is

```
public class CurrentAudioFormat {

    public static AudioFormat getAudioFormat(){
        float sampleRate = 44100;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
        int channels = 1; //mono
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean bigEndian = true;
        return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
    }
}
```

I tried to test this code on the following mp3 file:

```
File type ID:   MPG3
Num Tracks:     1
----
Data format:     2 ch,  44100 Hz, '.mp3' (0x00000000) 0 bits/channel, 0 bytes/packet, 1152 frames/packet, 0 bytes/frame
                no channel layout.
estimated duration: 104.176325 sec
audio bytes: 4167053
audio packets: 3988
bit rate: 320000 bits per second
packet size upper bound: 1052
maximum packet size: 1045
audio data file offset: 3169
optimized
audio 4591692 valid frames + 576 priming + 1908 remainder = 4594176
```

The system characteristics are:

- processor: Intel core i5, 1.4 GHz;
- RAM: DDR3, 4Gb
- OS: Mac OS X El Captain

It took roughly 5 minutes to extract the byte array from this mp3 file.

What are the possible bottlenecks and how can I improve them?

Comment: Why aren't you using `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(File)` to read the file?

Comment: I didn't know about the `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(File)`. Could you give me an example of using this format? I am getting a compile type error at the lines DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format); and line.open(format);

Comment: sometimes the buffers is not written to its last bit and using format.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); is going to read some previous chunks that should not be read you should use format.read(buffer, 0, bytesRead); i don't say that it is the problem but it is going to give you a bad audio sample with some noise

Answer (score 2):

To read the bytes you just need

```
while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

I dont know why you are reading twice.

To make sure that what you got is right try to resave it to a new audio file.

--

The standard way to read the audio file is

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream=null;
  try {
    audioInputStream=AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(file));
  }
  catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException auf) { auf.printStackTrace(); }
```

then you pass this audioInputStream to your reading method.

Comment: Thx for suggestion about saving data back to mp3 file. I did it and couldn't play it. I think there is an issue with the AudioFormat class i.e. I didn't specify it properly.

Comment: how do you read/write mp3? java cannot do it so you must have some outside library.

Comment: int count = format.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); where format is the instance of the AudioFormat class - this is I read mp3 file. I simply save the byte[] to the mp3 file. Could you then suggest any 3rd party libs to work with mp3 format in java?

Comment: there is this http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/docs/doc1.9.4/javazoom/spi/mpeg/sampled/file/MpegAudioFileReader.html which I use but there is also mp3agic which I havent used but some other guy has used - search on here or on the web - for now you can test with a .wav file