# Java FileInputStream FileOutputStream difference in the run

Tags: java, difference, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Could someone tell me why the 1. run is wrong? (The return code is 0, but the file written is only half of the original one.

Thanks in advance!

```
public class FileCopyFisFos {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("d:/Test1/OrigFile.MP4");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("d:/Test2/DestFile.mp4");

// 1. run
//        while (fis.read() != -1){
//            int len = fis.read();
//            fos.write(len);
//        }

// 2. run
//        int len;
//        while ((len = fis.read()) != -1){
//            fos.write(len);
//        }

        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You read a byte to find out whether you've reached the end of the stream, then discard it. You then read a second byte, and write it. You keep repeating that until you *do* reach the end of the stream... having discarded every other byte.

Comment: Obviously because you are calling read twice per iterationand use only second value

Comment: the first `fis.read()` , in the while condition, is forever forgotten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()) 's `read()` method follows this logic:

> ***Reads a byte of data** from this input stream. This method blocks if no input is yet available.*

So assigning the value of its return to a variable, such as:

```
while((len = fis.read())!= -1)
```

Is avoiding the byte of data just read from the stream to be forgotten, as every `read()` call will be assigned to your `len` variable.

---

Instead, this code bypasses one of every two bytes from the stream, as the `read()` executed in the `while` condition is never assigned to a variable. So the stream advances without half of the bytes being read (assigned to `len`):

```
while (fis.read() != -1) {      // reads a byte of data (but not saved)
   int len = fis.read();        // next byte of data saved
   fos.write(len);              // possible -1 written here    
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!! (Now I've got why it got only half of the original file volume.)

Comment: you're welcome! the point is, every read() call will make the stream advance. Glad you could fix it : )

Comment: No, it was you and buddies helped me on fixing it. (Acutally I should have noticed that due to the half KB as result.

Comment: BTW, what really makes the difference between write() with one parameter and with three paramters?
 byte[] bys = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = fis.read()) != -1){
            fos.write(bys);
//            fos.write(bys, 0, len);
        }

Comment: The first one https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write(byte[]) will write the entire length of the byte[] passed as parameter

Comment: The second one https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write(byte[],%20int,%20int) will write the number of bytes specified by len from the byte[] , also specifying the starting offset from where to start writing

Comment: Be aware that there is also a write(int) method, which also accepts one parameter(this one an int instead of a byte[]) : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write(int)

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately not really the case to me. The first alternative, with one parameter in write(), seems to be a never ending process and does not stop writing data till the disk is full.

Comment: You should debug that and check wether your stream is reaching EOF, as it should stop writting once the read is finished.

Comment: OK, thanks for the hint! Got it. Nice time!

Comment: Just noticed you are reading MP4 files; Be aware that you should wrap the InputStream into a ByteArrayInputStream or similar in order to get correct results. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828216/performance-issues-with-converting-mp3-file-input-stream-to-byte-output-stream Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks again! I think you've fixed the point. It was an example with a jpg and I've tried with a mp3 and also with mp4 by using FileInputStream/FileOutputStream. It works with byte properly, but maybe not with byte[]. I'll then check with ByteArrayOutputStream/ByteArrayInputStream. Thanks again!

Comment: @pojna more than welcome! May the force be with you while coding

Comment: @pojna JayC667's answer is better, as it gives much more info to this issue. Accept it witjout hesitation!

Comment: You are so kind and generous. I did and changed back. A friend in need is a friend indeed. The timely help is worth of course also the more structured hints and advice. BTW, your reply was concisely which is quite valuable for beginners, I just stick to that and thank you both as well as all the other volunteers for the contributions!

Answer (score 2):

@aran and others already pointed out the solution to your problem.

However there are more sides to this, so I extended your example:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileCopyFisFos {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final File src = new File("d:/Test1/OrigFile.MP4");
        final File sink = new File("d:/Test2/DestFile.mp4");

        {
            final long startMS = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long bytesCopied = copyFileSimple(src, sink);
            System.out.println("Simple copy transferred " + bytesCopied + " bytes in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startMS) + "ms");
        }
        {
            final long startMS = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long bytesCopied = copyFileSimpleFaster(src, sink);
            System.out.println("Simple+Fast copy transferred " + bytesCopied + " bytes in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startMS) + "ms");
        }
        {
            final long startMS = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long bytesCopied = copyFileFast(src, sink);
            System.out.println("Fast copy transferred " + bytesCopied + " bytes in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startMS) + "ms");
        }

        System.out.println("Test completed.");
    }

    static public long copyFileSimple(final File pSourceFile, final File pSinkFile) throws IOException {
        try (
                final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pSourceFile);
                final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pSinkFile);) {

            long totalBytesTransferred = 0;
            while (true) {
                final int readByte = fis.read();
                if (readByte < 0) break;

                fos.write(readByte);
                ++totalBytesTransferred;
            }
            return totalBytesTransferred;
        }
    }

    static public long copyFileSimpleFaster(final File pSourceFile, final File pSinkFile) throws IOException {
        try (
                final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pSourceFile);
                final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pSinkFile);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);) {

            long totalBytesTransferred = 0;
            while (true) {
                final int readByte = bis.read();
                if (readByte < 0) break;

                bos.write(readByte);
                ++totalBytesTransferred;
            }
            return totalBytesTransferred;
        }
    }

    static public long copyFileFast(final File pSourceFile, final File pSinkFile) throws IOException {
        try (
                final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pSourceFile);
                final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pSinkFile);) {

            long totalBytesTransferred = 0;
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[20 * 1024];
            while (true) {
                final int bytesRead = fis.read(buffer);
                if (bytesRead < 0) break;

                fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                totalBytesTransferred += bytesRead;
            }
            return totalBytesTransferred;
        }
    }

}
```

The hints that come along with that code:

- There is the java.nio package that usualy does those things a lot faster and in less code.
- Copying single bytes is 1'000-40'000 times slower that bulk copy.
- Using try/resource/catch is the best way to avoid problems with reserved/locked resources like files etc.
- If you solve something that is quite commonplace, I suggest you put it in a utility class of your own or even your own library.
- There are helper classes like BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream that take care of efficiency greatly; see example copyFileSimpleFaster().
- But as usual, it is the quality of the concept that has the most impact on the implementation; see example copyFileFast().
- There are even more advanced concepts (similar to java.nio), that take into account concepts like OS caching behaviour etc, which will give performance another kick.

Check my outputs, or run it on your own, to see the differences in performance:

```
Simple copy transferred 1608799 bytes in 12709ms
Simple+Fast copy transferred 1608799 bytes in 51ms
Fast copy transferred 1608799 bytes in 4ms
Test completed.
```

Comment: a complete answer to this, so more than welcome to honour you with the accepted tick! This answer deserves it more than mine

Comment: Phantasctic! That's a marvelous summary! You're right, the purpose of the assignment is to clearly tell the difference between byte, byte[] in FileOutputStream as well as in BufferedOutputStream. Will take a closer look at nio for it's new to me. Many thanks and nice period!